# Handling special characters in Grafana variable used in regex filter

Tags: regex, grafana, grafana-loki, logql, grafana-dashboard

I am using Grafana for visualizing my logs and came across a specific challenge related to handling special characters, specifically the square brackets ([...]).

Situation:

In one of my dashboards, I have messages like: ERROR: DoorBoard: SetErrorClass[Uart]: Connection timeout. The key segment here is [Uart].

To navigate to a detailed dashboard, I use the link: https://localhost:8443/d/mxQsIYaVk/inspect-promtail-log-details?orgId=1&from=now-7d&to=now&var-errorMsg=${__data.fields.message}. This sets a Grafana variable, errorMsg, to the clicked message.

In the detailed dashboard, I then use the query: {job="systemd-journal"} |~ .$errorMsg.| regexp(?PERROR:.*?)(\x1B[0m|\x1B[m|$)`` to filter logs based on this variable.

Problem:

When the message contains "[...]", it causes issues with the regex interpretation. For instance, "\[...\]" works perfectly. However, I am unsure about the best way to modify the variable or representation to handle this correctly.

Currently, I am considering a method to replace patterns within a Grafana variable, so the message "ERROR: Bill: SetErrorClass[SerialPort]: SYNC failed" would appear as "ERROR: Bill: SetErrorClass\[SerialPort\]: SYNC failed", thus making the variable play nicely with regex in the subsequent dashboard. But I haven't found a way to perform this transformation in Grafana.

Is there a way in Grafana to replace certain patterns within a variable? Or is there a different approach to sidestep this issue, perhaps at the regex level or another stage?

Comment: AFAIK,  you cannot do this only with Grafana. One of available workarounds is to create chained variable, and put into it escaped value from your initial variable. But this can be done only with some of data sources.